# Which Material version (v2 or v3) is Angular material based on?

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design

[Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/components/categories) is based on the [Material Design Specification](https://material.io).

Which angular material version belongs to which material design specification version (v1, v2, v3)?

| Angular Material Version | Material Design Version |
| --- | --- |
| 16 | ? |
| 15 | ? |
| 14 | ? |
| 13 | ? |
| 12 | ? |
| 11 | ? |
| 10 | ? |

Answer (score 6, accepted):

they are using material 2
how do I know?
go to the package.json of angular material for 15.2 and look for the dependencies
https://github.com/angular/components/blob/15.2.x/package.json

if they are using material 3 they would have `@material/web` dependency but instead you will find the material 2 dependencies

```
    "@material/animation": "15.0.0-canary.684e33d25.0",
    "@material/auto-init": "15.0.0-canary.684e33d25.0",
    "@material/banner": "15.0.0-canary.684e33d25.0",
    "@material/base": "15.0.0-canary.684e33d25.0",
    "@material/button": "15.0.0-canary.684e33d25.0",
    "@material/card": "15.0.0-canary.684e33d25.0",
    "@material/checkbox": "15.0.0-canary.684e33d25.0",
    "@material/chips": "15.0.0-canary.684e33d25.0",
    "@material/circular-progress": "15.0.0-canary.684e33d25.0",
    "@material/data-table": "15.0.0-canary.684e33d25.0",
    "@material/density": "15.0.0-canary.684e33d25.0",
    "@material/dialog": "15.0.0-canary.684e33d25.0",
    "@material/dom": "15.0.0-canary.684e33d25.0",
    "@material/drawer": "15.0.0-canary.684e33d25.0",
    "@material/elevation": "15.0.0-canary.684e33d25.0",
    "@material/fab": "15.0.0-canary.684e33d25.0",
    "@material/feature-targeting": "15.0.0-canary.684e33d25.0",
    "@material/floating-label": "15.0.0-canary.684e33d25.0",
    "@material/form-field": "15.0.0-canary.684e33d25.0",
    "@material/icon-button": "15.0.0-canary.684e33d25.0",
    "@material/image-list": "15.0.0-canary.684e33d25.0",
    "@material/layout-grid": "15.0.0-canary.684e33d25.0",
    "@material/line-ripple": "15.0.0-canary.684e33d25.0",
    "@material/linear-progress": "15.0.0-canary.684e33d25.0",
    "@material/list": "15.0.0-canary.684e33d25.0",
    "@material/menu": "15.0.0-canary.684e33d25.0",
    "@material/menu-surface": "15.0.0-canary.684e33d25.0",
    "@material/notched-outline": "15.0.0-canary.684e33d25.0",
    "@material/radio": "15.0.0-canary.684e33d25.0",
    "@material/ripple": "15.0.0-canary.684e33d25.0",
    "@material/rtl": "15.0.0-canary.684e33d25.0",
    "@material/segmented-button": "15.0.0-canary.684e33d25.0",
    "@material/select": "15.0.0-canary.684e33d25.0",
    "@material/shape": "15.0.0-canary.684e33d25.0",
    "@material/slider": "15.0.0-canary.684e33d25.0",
    "@material/snackbar": "15.0.0-canary.684e33d25.0",
    "@material/switch": "15.0.0-canary.684e33d25.0",
    "@material/tab": "15.0.0-canary.684e33d25.0",
    "@material/tab-bar": "15.0.0-canary.684e33d25.0",
    "@material/tab-indicator": "15.0.0-canary.684e33d25.0",
    "@material/tab-scroller": "15.0.0-canary.684e33d25.0",
    "@material/textfield": "15.0.0-canary.684e33d25.0",
    "@material/theme": "15.0.0-canary.684e33d25.0",
    "@material/tooltip": "15.0.0-canary.684e33d25.0",
    "@material/top-app-bar": "15.0.0-canary.684e33d25.0",
    "@material/touch-target": "15.0.0-canary.684e33d25.0",
    "@material/typography": "15.0.0-canary.684e33d25.0",
```